# Could i link csv from url into google spreadsheet?

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have updated day by day CSV file from this URL:

https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath_eueea_daily_ei/csv/data.csv

After importing the data into a google spreadsheet, Can I make that data auto-updated whenever the data are updated in the URL?

I have zero knowledge of API. Do I need to use it?

Comment: In your tags, `google-sheets-api` is included. In your situation, the CSV data is put using Sheets API? For example, can you provide your current script? About `I have zero knowledge of API.`, in this case, what API is that?

Comment: @Tanaike there is no api included in my sheets and i did not use any. I just want to make the data get updated everytime the url gets updated

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Answer (score 1):

The `IMPORTDATA` function will keep the data live, as the CSV is updated every day.

Put this in cell A1 on your Sheet.

`=IMPORTDATA("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath_eueea_daily_ei/csv/data.csv")`